# How do I use OnQueueComplete event in uploadify/uploadifive to send an email on queue complete?

Tags: php, javascript, email, events, uploadify

I am using uploadify/uploadifive to manage uploads to my site.  I would like to send an email each time the upload queue has completed. Both uploadify and uploadifive have an [OnQueueComplete event](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/onqueuecomplete-2/), with arguments that can be passed, e.g. 'count' returns the total number of uploads, so I presume that I would use this to trigger a PHP script which sends the email, but I am not sure how to do this and how to pass the 'count' argument to the script.  Here is an example of the way onQueueComplete is used:

```
'onQueueComplete' : function(uploads) {
            alert(uploads.successful + ' files were uploaded successfully.');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to make an Ajax call that will send an email from the server:

```
var sendEmailOnUploadComplete = function( uploads ) {
    //using jQuery
    $.post( '/sendEmail.php' );
};

 'onQueueComplete' : sendEmailOnUploadComplete
```

More info on jQuery.post here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.  I'm assuming your answer should read `$.post(...)`